# Карты яндекс как отключить скролл и включать по клику на карту

Tags: javascript, css, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Карты Яндекс как отключить скролл и включать по клику на карту. Помогите знаю что через Api но я догнать не могу даже как его подключить ? Это делается как библиотека js и в ней прописываешь api или как ?

Answer (score 5):

Как начать работать с API лучше всего расскажет [документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage/).

Отключить изменение масштаба при скролле можно через [поведение карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/behavior.ScrollZoom-docpage/): ScrollZoom. Есть пример, [как использовать поведения](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/behaviors).

Включить поведение по клику на карте можно так:

```
myMap.events.add('click', function(){
myMap.behaviors.enable('scrollZoom')
})
```

Вот [работающий пример.](https://jsfiddle.net/p27ywts4/2/)